# Problema con un ".bat" renombrar en bulk todos los archivos (jpg) de una carpeta

Tags: windows, shell-script, .bat

```
@echo off

set /p nombre_archivo=Introduce el nombre del archivo que quieres poner:

set /p ruta_archivos=Introduce la ruta de la carpeta donde se encuentran los archivos:

set contador=1

for %%a in ("%ruta_archivos%\*.jpg") do (
    ren "%%a" "%nombre_archivo% !contador!.jpg"
    set /a contador+=1
)

echo Archivos renombrados correctamente.

pause
```

Lo que el código debería hacer, es primero seleccionar el nombre que va a llevar el archivo ej. (Juegos Olímpicos) de una carpeta, ej (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Proyecto) y a ese nombre añadirle un número (Juegos Olímpicos 1,Juegos Olímpicos 2, etc.)

No se si me he explicado bien, estaré leyendo y comentando os si funciona o no, en referencia a lo que me digáis.

Si es imposible decírmelo sin problemas.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: En %%a van a aparecer los nombres de los archivos que hay en la carpeta, no el nombre con la ruta. Por lo tanto, la primera parte del ren debe incluir también la carpeta donde están los archivos. Lo mismo ocurre con la segunda parte(archivo destino). Para ver lo que está haciendo, te recomiendo que englobes todo el REN dentro de un ECHO, así podrás ver por pantalla qué instrucción estás ejecutando

Comment: @Jakala la parte del bucle me queda así:
 for %%a in ("%ruta_archivos%\*.jpg") do (
    set "archivo_antiguo=%%a"
    set "archivo_nuevo=%ruta_archivos%\%nombre_archivo% !contador!.jpg"
    echo ren "%archivo_antiguo%" "%archivo_nuevo%"
    ren "%archivo_antiguo%" "%archivo_nuevo%"
    set /a contador+=1
)
Aún así me da un error, si puedes localizar el fallo te lo agradecería, un saludo y buenas tardes

Comment: por favor traduci el titulo tambien!

Answer (score 0):

Para quien les pueda ser de utilidad les dejo este código para renombrar los archivos de un directorio por una secuencia numérica:

for /r %%a in (*.jpg) do (for /l %%c in (1, 1, 6) do (ren "%%a" "%%c.jpg"))

for /l %%c in (1, 1, 6) Esto significa un ciclo for de tipo lista donde la variable c tomará los valores numéricos que inician en 1, se incrementa en 1 por cada ciclo, y termina luego de 6 recorridos, con lo cuál los archivos de salida inician en el 1.jpg y terminan en el 6.jpg